# Autofac with web api not resolving dependencies

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, autofac

I'm having a hard time trying to understand why I can't seem to get autofac 3.5.2 (also tried with version 4.4) to work with Web Api 2.2 + Owin.

**I have a controller that requires a dependency of `IClass1`. It appears to be registered, but for some reason it fails to resolve at runtime. Any idea what the problem might be?**

The registration in question appears to be there (see line 4 - `Class1` registered as `IClass1`):

[image: Registrations]

And the lifetime scope is right, it is set to: AutofacWebRequest

[image]

## Code

### Registrations

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var suffix = typeof(DefaultHttpControllerSelector).GetField("ControllerSuffix", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

    if (suffix != null) suffix.SetValue(null, string.Empty);

    var container = InitializeDiContainer(app);
    var config = new HttpConfiguration
    {
        DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container)
    };

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
    app.UseWebApi(config);

    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var profile in container.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>())
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    });

    OnEndpointConfigurationCompleted(app, container);
}

private IContainer InitializeDiContainer(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    var allAssemblies = AssemblyUtils.GetAllAssemblies();

    builder.RegisterApiControllers("Endpoint", AssemblyUtils.GetEndpointAssemblies());

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AssemblyUtils.GetAllAssemblies())
        .Where(t => typeof(IReadModelService).IsAssignableFrom(t) ||
            typeof(IRepository).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerRequest()
        .PropertiesAutowired();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AssemblyUtils.GetAllAssemblies())
        .Where(t => typeof(IProvider).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerRequest()
        .PropertiesAutowired();

    var configFilePath = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "endpointConfig.json");

    builder.Register(ctx => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1Setting>(File.ReadAllText(configFilePath)))
        .InstancePerRequest();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

### Dependencies

```
public class Class1 : IClass1
{ }

public interface IClass1 : IReadModelService
{ }

public class Class1Setting
{
    public string DataSource { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

The controller fails to resolve the `IClass1` instance.

```
public class DeviceQueriesEndpoint : ApiController, IDeviceQueriesEndpoint
{
    private IClass1 _class1;


    public DeviceQueriesEndpoint(IClass1 class1)
    {
        _class1 = class1;
    }
}
```

## Exception

This is the exception I get at runtime:

*An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DeviceQueriesEndpoint'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.*

```
Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DeviceQueriesEndpoint'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = DeviceQueriesEndpoint (DelegateActivator), Services = [xpto.Middleware.Api.Device.Endpoint.DeviceQueriesEndpoint], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = ExternallyOwned ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = DeviceQueriesEndpoint (ReflectionActivator), Services = [xpto.Middleware.Api.Device.Endpoint.DeviceQueriesEndpoint], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'xpto.Middleware.Api.Device.Endpoint.DeviceQueriesEndpoint' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'xpto.ClassLibrary1.IClass1 class1' of constructor 'Void .ctor(xpto.ClassLibrary1.IClass1)'. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType) at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = DeviceQueriesEndpoint (ReflectionActivator), Services = [xpto.Middleware.Api.Device.Endpoint.DeviceQueriesEndpoint], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'xpto.Middleware.Api.Device.Endpoint.DeviceQueriesEndpoint' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'xpto.ClassLibrary1.IClass1 class1' of constructor 'Void .ctor(xpto.ClassLibrary1.IClass1)'. (See inner exception for details.)
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Registration.ExternalRegistrySource.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RegistrationsFor>b__2(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'xpto.Middleware.Api.Device.Endpoint.DeviceQueriesEndpoint' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'xpto.ClassLibrary1.IClass1 class1' of constructor 'Void .ctor(xpto.ClassLibrary1.IClass1)'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

## Things I've Tried

If I manually register the concrete type it works, which is odd:

```
builder.RegisterType<Class1>().As<IClass1>();
```

If I remove the constructor and manually try to resolve `IClass1` inside an action, it will still fail, which makes me believe that there's some kind of bug with the stack combination that I am using.

Comment: Is `IClass1` a `IReadModelService`, `IRepository` or `IProvider`?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer I updated the OP, and added the implementation of the Class1

Comment: Where are you (effectively) calling `builder.RegisterType<Class1>().As<IClass1>()` ? `DeviceQueriesEndpoint` wants an `IClass1`, not a `Class1Setting`, so the thing you highlighted in the screen shot isn't the right thing that's missing. What is the rest of the exception message - including the inner exception and stack trace? Can you post that? Usually it includes exactly which type it can't find.

Comment: @TravisIllig this bit is the one registering Class1 since IClass1 implements IReadModelService.

Comment: You can see in the screenshot that among other Class1 is registered as a IReadModelService.

Comment: Can we see the full exception with stack trace and inner exceptions for the failure case? Curious if it may point to something.

Comment: @TravisIllig see my last update. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Also, you said `builder.RegisterType<Class1>().As<IClass1>();` makes it work... If you add instance per request `builder.RegisterType<Class1>().As<IClass1>().InstancePerRequest()` does it still work?

Comment: It works both ways, but if I add InstancePerRequest and try to resolve the type within an action (Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IClass1));) it fails whereas without the InstancePerRequ‌est it works.

Comment: In WebAPI you don't resolve from the dependency resolver - you get the request lifetime scope off the request message.

Comment: @TravisIllig Yes you're right. But ignoring that secondary issue, the main problem is still there :( Automatic registration should work and it does not.

Comment: The reason I was asking about adding "InstancePerRequest" was to see if there's a lifetime scope issue. If registering the class without InstancePerRequest allows the controller to be resolved but adding InstancePerRequest causes it to fail it means you may be resolving the controller outside a request. Is that happening?

Comment: @TravisIllig we are getting a bit lost here, my bad sorry. The manual registration works with or without InstancePerRequest , the dependency gets injected into the constructor, no problem. I did try to resolve the dependency again inside an action but was doing something wrong as you already pointed out, it was just a test nothing else.

Comment: So to sum it all, this works: builder.RegisterType<Class1>().As<IClass1>().InstancePerRequest() and this doesn't: builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AssemblyUtils.GetAllAssemblies())
                .AssignableTo<IClass1>()
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerRequest(); even tho I can see the dependency in the registration with the right services and autofac scope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137852/discussion-between-travis-illig-and-marco).

Comment: Actually this had nothing to do with Autofac. I was using Assembly.LoadFile which was not taking in consideration the assembly bindings. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this had nothing to do with Autofac. I was using Assembly.LoadFile which was not taking in consideration the assembly bindings.